# Can I get both a visa free entry and a visa to Vietnam and seamlessly transition between them?

Tags: visas, passports, vietnam, swedish-citizens

Can I get both a visa free entry and a visa to Vietnam and seamlessly transition between them?

Is it possible to apply for a visa to Vietnam in say Khon Kaen (Thailand) from 15 of February to 13th of May and then go to the Vietnamese border on the 1st of February and get a Visa free entry for 15 days?

And if that's possible, is it also possible to just stay in Vietnam first for 15 days visa free and after that another 3 months with the previously acquired visa without a need to cross the border again?

I have a Swedish passport.